# How to make variables accessible in all controllers in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I added some variables to the bottom of the "CI_Controller" class like so:

```
$data['foo'] = 'bar';
$data['animal'] = 'dog';
$data['justin_beiber'] = 'terrible';
```

Since I want these variables to be accessible on ALL my controllers and since all the controllers extends this CI_Controller, I figured this would work:

```
echo $data['foo'];
die();
```

I put this in a controller that extends CI_Controller. But it doesn't output anything. How to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe proper use of the config options would help you.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

You can call a config item from anywhere in the CI structure.

and as per why your variables aren't echoing: You can set protected vars in a class to make them visible by inheritance, but I don't think that's the best way to go about doing this. At least not without knowing why you want $data['foo'] available everywhere without the use of a helper.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great idea. However here's my ultimate goal: I want to make all these variables accessible in all my views. But now I have to do something like this: $data['foo'] = $this->config->item('foo'); I have to do this in every controller. Is there a way to pass these variables into my $data var so that when I pass this var in my views from my controllers, the $data var will automatically contain all those vars previously defined in the config file? Basically I don't want to repeat that variable assignment code in every controller.

Comment: Maybe try extending the controller with MY_Controller, and call $this->load->vars(array('foo' => 'whatever')); in the constructor...

Comment: I more or less meant that you would call $this->config->item('foo') in place of $data['foo'] or just $foo, but that's not really an answer to your question. At least the config option is an option none the less.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you [extend your main controller and not modify it](http://upshots.org/codeigniter/codeigniter-2-extending-the-native-controller-ci_controller). Also make sure your controllers extend your new controller (MY_controller) and not the original, since we have something like:

```
class  MY_Controller  extends  CI_Controller  {
// constructor and variables defined here
}
```

Also note that you'd have to call your variables like this: `$this->foo['bar']` if you decide to use it this way... For 'normal' variable calling (`$foo['bar']`), make a [CI helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) and [autoload](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html) it.